# Javascript: inputs on keyup event calculate their sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, sum

I am new to javascript and its events. Here is my html code for table, where i have a income title and its respective price.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="incomeId">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> sn </th>
      <th> Title of income </th>
      <th> Price </th>
      <th> Action </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <select name="name" id="inputID" class="form-control">
          <option value=""> -- Select One --</option>                           
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="income_price" class="form-control income" value="" title="" required="required">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td> Total: <div class="total" id="total"></div> </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="add-new">Add New Income</button>
```

To add new row in table javascript code is,

```
$('#add-new').on('click', function () {
        $("#incomeId").each(function () {

            var tds = '<tr>';

            jQuery.each($('tbody tr:last td', this), function () {
                tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
            });

            tds += '</tr>';
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });
    });
```

But I want to get the price from all price section and sum to each in a total section before creating new row in table. When I create the new row then the recently created price should be add to the previous total price.
Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: How does your question relate to the multiple keyup in the title?

Comment: I want to use the keyup event to get the value from each input box and added to the total section.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a bunch of dynamically inserted input's that you want to bind to a `updateTotal` event handler?

Easiest option is to simply bind your event handler to a static wrapper element. I'd suggest a form element, but since you haven't got one in your example, the table body may be another option.

```
$('table#incomeId > tbody').on('keyup', 'input', function(e){

       var total = 
            $(e.delegateTarget)
                .find('input')
            .map(function(){
                return parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
            })
            .get()
            .reduce(function(a,b){
                return a + b;
            });

       $('#total').text(total);


    });
```

```js
$('#add-new').on('click', function() {
  $("#incomeId").each(function() {
  
   var tr = $('tbody > tr:last', this).clone();
   tr.find('input').val('');
   var sntd = tr.find('td:first');
   var sn = parseInt(sntd.text()) + 1;
   sntd.text(sn);
   
   $('tbody', this).append(tr);
   
   
   
   return;

  });
});

$('table#incomeId > tbody').on('keyup', 'input', function(e) {

  var total =
    $(e.delegateTarget)
    .find('input')
    .map(function() {
      return parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    })
    .get()
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });

  $('#total').text(total);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="incomeId">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        sn
      </th>
      <th>
        Title of income
      </th>
      <th>
        Price
      </th>
      <th>
        Action
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <select name="name" id="inputID" class="form-control">
          <option value=""> -- Select One --</option>                           
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="income_price" class="form-control income" value="" title="" required="required">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Total:
        <div class="total" id="total"></div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="add-new">Add New Income</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. This is what exactly i want.Another things sir, How to increment the serial number of table after adding the new row in table? If you have any idea about this please share.

Comment: Generally I prefer using data attributes on my elements or storing a counter internally, rather than parsing DOM nodes. But for the sake of sticking with what you know, the easiest way it to find the serial number `td` element, parse the integer text, increment and set it. I've updated the example above for you too see. (note that the example above doesn't account for things like deleting an input, which may cause breaks in the serial numbers)

Comment: Thank you sir. Say me one thing , How do i manage the both serial number and deleting row in a nice way.